# Getting DisplayFor(m => m.Property) to show line breaks and formatting?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a problem with my View in that when I am editing something using `TextAreaFor` any line breaks or formatting I insert are saved and when I edit the same element, it will still be shown like this:

> Need something to keep the family entertained this Winter? Or looking for the perfect Christmas gift? You’ll find both at CD WOW!
>
> With this offer, Members can:
>
> • Search a huge range of music, movies, TV, books and games.
>
> • Get the latest releases direct to your door for Christmas, with free worldwide shipping.

But when I use `DisplayFor` or just `@Model.Property` it will display like this:

> Need something to keep the family entertained this Winter? Or looking for the perfect Christmas gift? You’ll find both at CD WOW! With this offer, Members can: • Search a huge range of music, movies, TV, books and games. • Get the latest releases direct to your door for Christmas, with free worldwide shipping.

What should I be using to display it in the format shown in `TextAreaFor`?

Comment: I guess one way is to display it in a `TextAreaFor` and then disable the field?

Comment: @mattytommo Interesting idea, how do you disable the field out of interest?

Comment: `@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Property, new { disabled = "disabled" })`

Comment: no problems, I've added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `<pre>` tag:

```
<pre>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Property)
</pre>
```

Another possibility is to write a custom helper that will replace the new lines (`\r\n`) with `<br/>` tags and use it like this:

```
@Html.DislpayFormattedFor(x => x.Property)
```

and here's how the custom helper could be defined:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString DislpayFormattedFor<TModel>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, string>> expression
    )
    {
        var value = Convert.ToString(
            ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).Model
        );
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        value = string.Join(
            "<br/>",
            value.Split(
                new[] { Environment.NewLine }, 
                StringSplitOptions.None
            ).Select(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode)
        );

        return new HtmlString(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This changes the formatting though. Latter option sounds good though

Comment: I have updated my answer to elaborate a little more on the second option.

Comment: I'd say that method is a little extravagant. Just used `.Replace()` instead

Comment: Oh no, don't use only Replace. Make sure you properly HTML encode your output or you open a huge XSS hole in your site.

Comment: I get the error `No overload for method DisplayFormattedFor takes 1 arguments`

Comment: Did you brought the namespace into which this helper is defined into scope in your view? How are you calling this method? The lambda expression that you pass must return a **string** property on your view model: `@Html.DislpayFormattedFor(x => x.Property)` where Property must be of type **string**. That's how I defined the signature of the helper: `Expression<Func<TModel, string>> expression`.

Comment: Yup yup. The static class you defined takes two arguments, but the View code only gives one argument

Comment: No, it doesn't take 2 arguments. It takes only 1 argument which is the expression. This is an extension method. Please read about extension methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx Notice the `this` keyword before the first parameter which makes it an extension method meaning that you could invoke it on an instance of `HtmlHelper<TModel>`.

Comment: Ha. Sorry, I was being stupid and had HtmlExtensions.DisplayFormattedFor. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the field? That way you can use the existing `TextAreaFor`:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Property, new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

Answer (score 0):

use <pre> tag or add this css property to your div/span tag :

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

example :

```
<div style="white-space: pre-wrap;">
  my
  multiline
  text
</div>
```